# How to capture crashes in iOS Swift 3.0 using only iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crash, crash-dumps

I am trying to write some basic code to capture crashes in iOS 10+ using Swift 3.0 without using third party libraries.

I found the following functions:

```
// Capturing exceptions 

NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
        print("Exception: \(exception.name) \(exception.reason!)\(exception.description)")
        print(exception.callStackSymbols)
    }

    // Capturing other crashes - **is this enough ????**
    // I wrote these in application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, but these don't get called. 
    signal(SIGABRT) {(a) in
        print(a)
    }

    signal(SIGABRT){(a) in
        print(a)
    }

    signal(SIGILL){(a) in
        print(a)
    }

    signal(SIGSEGV){(a) in
        print(a)
    }

    signal(SIGFPE){(a) in
        print(a)
    }

    signal(SIGBUS){(a) in
        print(a)
    }
    signal(SIGPIPE){(a) in
        print(a)
    }
```

1 - Are those methods enough?

2 - If so where should I call them to capture the crashes?

In order to **trigger a crash** I wrote the following method in ViewDidLoad of the only ViewController object that I have in the project:

[image]

However this method gives me an **EXC_BREAKPOINT** and not one of the crashes above.

3 - How can I capture **EXC_BREAKPOINT** programmatically?

4 - **Is there some other way that I can try triggering a crash?**

Answer (score 0):

You're aware iOS has TestFlight and you can just get any crashes for your app from Apple's web site?

It's fine if you're doing this for educational purposes, but otherwise, you don't need to write crash-handling code.

If you're just doing this for fun, I think your confusion comes from the fact that EXC_BREAKPOINT is a CPU exception, not an ObjC-exception. Those are delivered to your application using standard Unix signal handlers, so you'll have to use that instead.

Comment: I am doing this just for fun and educational purposes. In merit of the signal handlers, would you agree on those I posted in my answer?  I modified it on my app using "signal(SIGTRAP){(a) in print(a) }". Unfortunately, when I run my app the print code does not execute. Am I missing something? How can I get that print to occur? Thanks!